# Swiffy Text & Image Compression (blurry)

Tags: html, flash, compression, google-swiffy, swiffy

Is anyone else having problems using Swiffy to create swf files into HTML5? Everytime we use it - the images and text gets blurry.

The original flash file is not blurry - but already the images are compressed.

Does anyone know how the swiffy automatic compression works? It seems random

I've tried using vector vs raster, tried making the overall file size under 50KB (should be plenty as upload is usually 100Kb max).

Its happened on variety of sizes - seemingly without rhyme or reason.

Ie. sometimes leaderboards are fine, but mrecs get blurry. Sometimes leaderboards come out crisper than the mrecs!?

I've seen another answer on here saying someone else has the problem with vector objects - and the feedback was to make sure it sits on an actual pixel. Ie. 130px Y axis instead of 130.5 Y axis. But this is not making a difference for me.

Any other suggestions?

--

Additionally - what do people think is the best program to do html5 display banners? Adobe Edge, Google WebDesigner, etc? Seems there's complications with each.

Attached is an example: [Swiffy vs Flash Swf Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkUFt.png)

Thanks in advance!! Any tips appreciated